# Достать текст из HTML страницы после её загрузки с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, регулярные-выражения, telegram

Я не силен в JS! Необходима помощь знающего специалиста) Есть  скрипт, добавляющий на страницу виджет поста из Телеграм:

```
<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?21" data-telegram-post="postname/22" data-width="100%"> </script>
```

После загрузки страницы этот скрипт добавляет в < body > див блок Телеграм. Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На странице присутствует код, который проверяет HTML страницы на наличие знака %, а затем выводит количество процентов до знака (достает из кода страницы все числовые значения до знака %):

```
var markup = document.documentElement.outerHTML
var regexp = /(\d\d)%/gim
var match = regexp.exec(markup)
var comments = ''

while (match != null) {
    comments += match[1].trim() + '<br/>'
    match = regexp.exec(markup)
}

document.getElementById('comments').outerHTML = comments
```

Задача: Необходимо, чтобы скрипт анализировал HTML всей страницы, а затем доставал количество процентов из блока на скрине

Проблема: Скрипт анализирует html сайта до его загрузки, следовательно не "видит" в коде сайта див блок Телеграм из скрина выше.

Вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы код проверки HTML на знак % проверял код Телеграм виджета в том числе?

Comment: Событие DOMContentLoaded пробовали? если нет, то повесьте на window

Comment: К сожалению, даже когда пробую запустить скрипт после загрузки всего контента на странице, он не считывает iframe с Телеграм. Видимо, тут дело в том, что в принципе с подгружаемым iframe нельзя взаимодействовать из за политики безопасности

Comment: Если содержимое iframe находиться на другом домене (а у вас это так, контент Телеграм поставляет сторонний плагин), то доступ к содержимому iframe блокируется политикой безопасности Same-Orgin, и без явного разрешения от плагина (CORS, postMessage и.т.п) для вашего домена вы не можете получить элементы из iframe